# Create Angular 9 Library (ng-packagr) that allow import of single modules

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular9, ng-packagr

I created a angular [library](http://%20https://github.com/DevMonkeysDE/mark6) with angular 9 cli. What I noticed: I can only include modules by loading the whole library:

[image]

Of course this makes no sense in a real world application. I want to be able to load each module individually. What am I doing wrong? Why can't he find the image component under `@devmonkeys/mark6/image`

I linked the repository because I don't know exactly what it is. I think this makes more sense than posting the code of 6 possible files here.

What I mean exactly: @angular/material for example, each component has its own path to avoid loading the whole library into the app during build. https://material.angular.io/components/button/api as an component namend MatButton. to import it we must use: `{MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';` i also want this, because it makes no sense to load the whole libary in my code only because i want 1 component.

Comment: What do you mean by "loading the whole library"? I checked the project on GitHub and the modules of the library are added to the imports of the application one-by-one, so the user of the library is able to import only the wished modules.

Comment: With @angular/material for example each component has its own path to avoid loading the whole library into the app during build. https://material.angular.io/components/button/api as an example import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';